# jqGrid Modal Popup Order of Buttons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can you change the display order of the Submit/Cancel buttons on the jqGrid Modal Popup?

I've been looking for a property in the editGridRow method but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no option which allows you to change the order of the buttons directly, but you can examine the structure of the Edit/Add form and find out that the Submit and Cancel buttons has ids: "sData" and "cData". Both buttons has the same parent. So you can use for example the [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) event of the [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) method in the form

```
beforeShowForm: function($form){
    var cancelButton = $form.parent().find("#cData");
    cancelButton.parent().prepend(cancelButton);
}
```

to place the Cancel button on the first place.

On [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithContextmenuCancelButtonFirstOnEdit.htm) I use the `beforeShowForm` for the row editing. So just select a row and click the Edit button or double click on a row. You will see that the Cancel button are placed before the Submit button.